# Nested request Rxjs Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a list of items. Each item contains the name of a file. I need the name of each file. With each name make a new request and get the data file
First request looks like->[image: first item]

The goal is get the list and get the name of the image and do a new request for each item-image to get the path of the image and finaly append the path to the first item list
The goal looks like   *your text*[image: The goal]->

The code gets [image: my try]

```
entradas$.pipe(
mergeMap(entradas=>forkJoin 
 (entradas.map(ent=> 
 this.entradaService.getStaticSingularImage(ent.imagen))))) 
 .subscribe(data=>console.log(data))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code to combine the response and the details together.

```
entradas$
.pipe(
    mergeMap(entradas=>{
       return forkJoin(entradas.map(entrada => {
           return this.entradaService
                      .getStaticSingularImage(entrada.imagen)
                      .pipe(map((response) => {
                         return { 
                            entrada: entrada,
                            response
                         }
                      }));
       });
    })
)
.subscribe(data=>console.log(data))
```

Comment: It works!! Thanks a lot. I just changed the final answer to fit this :   entrada: {...entrada , imagen_url: response}

Comment: Great, glad to help. yeah, you can change it to make it much comfortable for you